# Do Quarks Exist?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, quantum-chromodynamics, quarks, confinement

**Do Quarks Really Exist?**

*Is there any experiment which can confirm the existence of Quarks and what kind of force is that which binds them to form neutron and proton?*

Comment: If you really want people to answer questions on this site, it is required to do a minimum of effort first. So why don’t you try Google and Wikipedia first and then tell us what you don’t understand there?

Comment: Hi @Kushagra welcome to the 21st century. The 1990 Nobel prize in Physics was awarded for the first evidence of quarks, based on experiments from the 1970's (https://physicstoday.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.2809944)

Comment: @J.Delaney no need to be passive aggressive here. The second half of your comment was indeed helpful

Comment: @J.Delaney Note that the observation from deep inelastic scattering at SLAC indeed showed three lumps inside proton, which is a strong support for Quark Model, but it's not conclusive

Comment: Thankyou for all your comment you may not know that I am just a high school student who is studying very basic nuclear physics, and I have no idea about the quarks and all and I doubted that they even existed I tried to find on web from last week but wasn't able to get my desired answer so I just asked I am really sorry if my question wasted your precious time sir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To supply an answer instead of a comment containing the answer:

Direct experimental evidence of quarks inside protons and neutrons was obtained by shooting electrons at protons and neutrons with enough energy to actually penetrate those particles. So instead of just bouncing off the electron cloud surrounding the atoms containing them, the electrons went all the way inside the constituent nucleons and bounced off the quarks themselves.

This required an electron beam accelerator *two miles long* (!!!) which was built at Stanford University for this express purpose (called *deep inelastic scattering*) in the early 1960's and began collecting evidence around 1966-67. By about 1970-71, the evidence was clear that there were indeed three little point-like objects inside every proton and neutron and the strong nuclear force was what confined them there.

Comment: How is parton distribution inside proton a direct evidence for quarks?

Comment: Read Riordan's book 'The Hunting Of The Quark" for the details. -NN

Comment: Thank you. I was going through "Introduction to elementary particles" by Griffiths where he mentioned that this proton substructure "is strong support for he quark model, obviously, but still not conclusive". Even, the twistor particle program during that time allowed for substructure, but those were termed as substructure of twistor internal degrees of freedom of single particle states. It seemed like proton substructure is not an unique feature about the quark model

Comment: @KP99, When Feynman heard about the deep inelastic scattering data, he shit his pants and went to town on the rest of the community, which listened to him because of his stature. Riordan explains this. However chagrined the creators of alternative models may have been at the time, Feynman carried the day and they went off to lick their wounds. It was the stuff of Nobel prizes and Feynman knew it.

Comment: Were those 'deep inelastic scattering' results independently reproduced on a different particle accelerator?

Comment: @sesm, yes. see Riordan's *The Hunting Of The Quark* for the complete story.